# On Page Complete Load show alert box

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to show one alert box after my application home page completely loads.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Duplicate of:[Calling Java Script Alert Function when entire ASP.Net Page gets load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091445/calling-java-script-alert-function-when-entire-asp-net-page-gets-load?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery libaray

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then use

```
$(function() {
    alert( "ready!" );
});
```

or

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert( "ready!" );
});
```